# Errorbar plot transparency overlapping

Tags: matplotlib, alpha, errorbar

In an errorbar matplotlib plot, the main line, the markers and the errorbars of a same color overlap each other on their countour when I use the alpha parameter. Although my goal was to have a transparency between the two different colors, but not within the same color, as if same color lines, markers and errorbars were only one object. Is that possible?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Time = np.array([1, 2, 3])
Green = np.array([3, 5, 9])
Blue = np.array([4, 7, 13])

Green_StDev = np.array([0.6, 0.6, 0.7])
Blue_StDev = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.6])

plt.errorbar(Time, Green, Green_StDev, marker='o', c='green', alpha=0.5)

plt.errorbar(Time, Blue, Blue_StDev, marker='o', c='blue', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Like the example below, but with transparency only between different color objects, differently of the example above.

[image]

Comment: I cannot understand... Do you want the transparence only on the overlapping markers?

Comment: Between all the objects of a same color from the other color, but no transparency on same color objects

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot draw them as one single object since they (marker and error bar) are drawn individually. However, to make it more 'aesthetic', you could redraw a non-transparent marker:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Time = np.array([1, 2, 3])
Green = np.array([3, 5, 9])
Blue = np.array([4, 7, 13])

Green_StDev = np.array([0.6, 0.6, 0.7])
Blue_StDev = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.6])

plt.errorbar(Time, Green, Green_StDev, marker='o', c='green', alpha=0.5)
# Add additional marker
plt.scatter(Time, Green,marker='o', c='green')

plt.errorbar(Time, Blue, Blue_StDev, marker='o', c='blue', alpha=0.5)
# Add additional marker
plt.scatter(Time, Blue, marker='o', c='blue')

plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. The markers will then have a slightly different color and, if they overlap, one will cover the other, since they're non-transparent

Comment: How about using different marker styles for each line (crosses or dots instead of big circles), so they don't fully overlap each other?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to contour the situation. Anyway, it's an issue to think about for the developers. Thanks mate